# Как скрыть в консоли цифру при вводе python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
numberS = input("Желаете продолжить?\n"
                      "Если да, то нажмите 1, если нет, то любую клавишу ")
```

Как сделать чтобы когда нажимаешь на `1`, то она в консоль не выводилась. А просто происходило действие которое она даёт?

Answer (score 3):

Подробнее о [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass).

```
import getpass

numberS = getpass.getpass("Желаете продолжить?\nЕсли да, то нажмите 1, если нет, то любую клавишу: ")
print(numberS)
```